# openfire - Chat Application using smack

Tags: android, mysql, openfire, smack

I am creating the chat application using smack library.
Issue was i am not able to connect in openfire. It showing exception

```
 D/SMACK: SENT (0): <response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>dXNlcm5hbWU9IndhemlkYSIscmVhbG09ImlzY2hvb2xzeXN0ZW0ubmV0Iixub25jZT0iRC9zTkxxNCtua1FaSHlFM0VVeEtTT3l5ekE1U2dGK21sdWJkLzFoKyIsY25vbmNlPSJpVER4VzAyNjI2Z09NMnQydDMwMFk1TEd4MklkUGJSZSIsbmM9MDAwMDAwMDEscW9wPWF1dGgsZGlnZXN0LXVyaT0ieG1wcC9pc2Nob29sc3lzdGVtLm5ldCIscmVzcG9uc2U9NTQ1Y2NlZGJkOTkyMjMwZDg5NmE3YmFhNGI3ZDI1YzQsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOA==</response>
 03-04 14:11:27.161 23011-23106/D/SMACK: RECV (0): <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
 03-04 14:11:27.163 23011-23068/W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using DIGEST-MD5: not-authorized
 03-04 14:11:27.163 23011-23068/W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticationFailed(SASLAuthentication.java:365)
 03-04 14:11:27.163 23011-23068/W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1033)
 03-04 14:11:27.163 23011-23068/W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
 03-04 14:11:27.163 23011-23068/W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
 03-04 14:11:27.163 23011-23068/W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/53991)  is the same issue. Have a look.